# Polymer data binding from javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer, interact.js

I'm trying to implement a drag-n-drop using Polymer.  When data is dragged onto the child element, I want to write it back to its parent for the property that's assigned to it.  However, when using the native binding functionality, `parent1`'s children will overwrite `parent2`'s properties.

I've tried to overwrite using the parent's `id` field but can't get past the shadow DOM (this isn't persistent):

```
Polymer.dom(document.getElementById('id')).node.x = data
```

For example, here's what I want to do:

> `[a,b,c]` dragged to `child1` --> assign to `parent1.x`
>
> `[1,2,3]` dragged to `child2` --> assign to `parent2.x`

Note `this.data` functions but assigns `[a,b,c]` from `child1` to both `parent1.x` and `parent2.x` as if it were a static variable.

Here's the *child* code:

```
<dom-module id=“child">
    <template>
        {{data}}
    </template>
</dom-module>

</body>

<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is: “child",
            properties: {
                data: {
                    type: Array,
                    notify: true,
                },
                id: {type: String}
            },
            addData: function (parent, attribute) {
                //This isn’t persistent
                parent.attribute = window.attributeData[attribute].data;
                //This overwrites x & y for both parents
                this.data = window.attributeData[attribute].data;
            },
            ready: function () {
                var child = this;
                interact('.dropzone')
                        .dropzone({overlap: 'center'})
                        .accept('.draggable')
                        //This event fires when the attribute has been dropped
                        .on('drop', function (event) {
                            child.addData(parent, attribute);
                            //event.relatedTarget.textContent = '';
                        });
            }
        });
    }());
</script>
```

Note I'm calling the update function from the drop-listener built into `interact.js`.

*Parent:*

```
<dom-module id=“parent">
    <template>
        <span>{{x}}</span>
        <child data={{x}}></child>
        <span>{{y}}</span>
        <child data={{y}}></child>
    </template>
</dom-module>

</body>

<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is: “parent",
            properties: {
                x: {
                    type: Array
                },
                y: {
                    type: Array
                }
            },
            setData: function(attr, data) {
                this.attr = data;
            }
        });
    }());
</script>
```

*index.html:*

```
<parent></parent>
<parent></parent>
```

Lastly, `Polymer.dom` when called from code or when called from *Inspect Element* have different behaviors. From the inspector, when I use this to assign to the property, it WORKS! But not from within the object.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most idea approach, but in case anyone else stumbles across the same problem:

*From the sending element:*

```
var forward = new CustomEvent('eventToBeFired', {
                    detail: { data: data }
                });
document.querySelector('element-id').dispatchEvent(forward);
```

*From the receiving element:*

```
Polymer({
        is: "element-id",
        listeners: {
            'eventToBeFired': 'functionToExcecute'
        },
        functionToExecute: function(e){
             e.detail.data;
        }
})
```

If someone has a better approach please add!